# Controller Action Not Reaching in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, odata

I have a OData web api using ADO.NET Framework in which the controller action is somehow not being reached.

The API correctly receives the HTTP request and parses it to go to the correct action but the action is not reached.

And in return the chrome browser shows the authentication window.

I have been debugging so long but cannot figure out how to solve this.

The controller is (stripped version):

```
 public class DataController : ODataController
 {
    private readonly DataModel DataAccessModel = new DataModel();


   public DataController()
   {
      ....... 
   }

   [HttpGet, EnableQuery]
   public IQueryable<Record> GetRecord(ODataQueryOptions<Record> options)
   {

       try
       {
           IQueryable<ActivationRequestLog> result;
           try
           {

               result = DataAccessModel.Recordss;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
              ......
           }
      } 

  } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have Windows Auth setup in your project in Startup.Auth class?

Comment: Try to add [AllowAnonymous] on top of the method?

Comment: Does the `[HttpGet]` attribute automatically map any function to the OData GET function? If not, try using `public IQueryable<Record> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Record> options)` instead of `public IQueryable<Record> GetRecord(ODataQueryOptions<Record> options)`. Also it would be good if you provide the `WebApiConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how the controller has been registered in the WebApiConfig class?

If you're using the ODataConventionModelBuilder, then you have to follow certain naming conventions for controllers of entity sets.

e.g. If I register an Airlines entity set of type Airline

```
        builder.EntitySet<Airline>("Airlines");
```

....then by default/convention I need to implement

```
public class AirlinesController : ODataController<Airline>
   {
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Airline> Get()
        {
            DB db = Request.GetContext();
            return db.Airlines();
        }
   }
```